# Sort a list based on the order of another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Tuple<string, Node>>` and a `List<NodeResponse>`. Both `Node` and `NodeResponse` contain a `NodeId`.

Here are the exact data structures used:

```
class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
    public string NodeId { get; set; } 
}

class NodeResponse
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string NodeId { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

List<Tuple<string, Node> tasks = new List<Tuple<string, Node>>();

List<NodeResponse> responses = new List<NodeResponse>();
```

I want `responses` ordered by the *position of the `NodeId` in the other list (`tasks`)*. In other words, a response corresponding to an earlier task should appear before a response corresponding to a later task.

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried already?

Comment: I didn't consider it necessary to show my attempts how to solve this problem. I'm sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sortedResponses = from nodeResponse in response
                      orderby tasks.FindIndex(t => t.Item2.NodeId == nodeResponse.NodeId)
                      select nodeResponse;
```

This uses [List.FindIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindIndex_System_Predicate__0__) to find the index of the first element in a list matching a certain predicate.

Asymptotic performance will be bad (`O(m*n)`, with `m` and `n` denoting the number of items in the two lists, respectively), so don't use this for huge lists. If this turns out to be a performance bottleneck, create a mapping from `NodeId`s to indexes first:

```
var nodeIdToIndex = 
    tasks.Select(t => t.Item2.NodeId).Distinct().
    ToDictionary(nodeId => nodeId,
                 nodeId => tasks.FindIndex(t => t.Item2.NodeId == nodeId));

var sortedResponses = 
    from nodeResponse in response
    orderby nodeIdToIndex[nodeResponse.NodeId]
    select nodeResponse;
```

Comment: Downvoter: Feedback to improve my answer would be appreciated...